# How do I set the style of the text in DateFormat in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

[image]

```
InkWell(
          child: TextFormField(
            readOnly: true,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            onTap: () async {
              DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
                  context: context,
                  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                  firstDate: DateTime(1900),
                  lastDate: DateTime.now());
              if (pickedDate != null) {
                setState(() {
                  _date.text = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(pickedDate);
                });
              }
            },
            controller: _date,
                hintStyle: bmiTextForm,
                hintText: 'Doğum Gününüz'),
          ),
        ),
```

HintStyle on the first image changes after selecting a date. How can I set the hintStyle of the DateFormat?

Comment: i am not sure what you want properly from your question but what I understood id that you want to change the properties of the text after the date is selected. `TextFormField(
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
)` this code will allow you to change the input textstyle. Hope this helps. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the same textStyle on `TextFormField`'s style as you did for hintText.

```dart
controller: _date,
style: bmiTextForm,
decoration: InputDecoration(
  hintStyle: bmiTextForm,
  hintText: 'Doğum Gününüz',
),
```